# Is there way to shutdown ignite node gracefully?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I came across this xml code snippet to shutdown the ignite/gridgain node gracefully.

Can someone provide complete xml code for the below line? In which section of XML code do I need to add the below line? i.e persistent section or cache section or generic section.

```
<property name="shutdownPolicy" value="GRACEFUL"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/starting-nodes#shutting-down-nodes):

> A graceful shutdown allows the node to finish critical operations and correctly complete its lifecycle. The proper procedure to perform a graceful shutdown is as follows:
>
> 1. Stop the node using one of the following methods:
>
> - programmatically call Ignite.close()
> - programmatically call System.exit()
> - send a user interrupt signal. Ignite uses a JVM shutdown hook to execute custom logic before the JVM stops. If you start the node by running `ignite.sh` and don’t detach it from the terminal, you can stop the node by hitting Ctrl+C.
>
> 2. Remove the node from the baseline topology. This step may not be necessary if baseline auto-adjustment is enabled.

About shutdownPolicy configuration

> `<property name="shutdownPolicy" value="GRACEFUL"/>`

This tag should be put into IgniteConfiguration like this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="shutdownPolicy" value="GRACEFUL"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**NOTE: Node will stop if and only if it does not store any unique partitions, that don't have another copies in the cluster.**